# SharePoint List Data

Tags: data

I recently created a SharePoint list for empployee's to make requests for leave and edited the list so that users could only see and edit what they add. I now have two questions:

1. Will I be able to see all of the data as the administrator of the SP list? I need to be able to export all entries to Excel for analysis and record-keeping.
2. Would an end user be able to export entered data to Excel and see everyone's data?